# Functions in $L^p$ and $L^q$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, solution-verification

For any two different numbers $p,q\in[1,\infty)$ find functions $f\in L^p \setminus L^q$  and $g\in L^q \setminus L^p$.

Solution: let 
$$f(x)=x^{-1/p}(1+|\log x|)^{-2/p}$$
Then 
$$\int|f|^p = \int_0^\infty x^{-1}(1+|\log x|)^{-2} =
\int_0^1 x^{-1}(1-\log x)^{-2} + \int_1^\infty x^{-1}(1+\log x)^{-2} \\
=\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac {du}{(1-u)^2} = \int_1^\infty \frac {2du}{u^2}<\infty$$
Let 
$$g(x)=x^{-1/q}(1+|\log x|)^{-2/q}$$
Then 
$$\int|g|^q = \int_0^\infty x^{-1}(1+|\log x|)^{-2} =
\int_0^1 x^{-1}(1-\log x)^{-2} + \int_1^\infty x^{-1}(1+\log x)^{-2} \\
= \int_{-\infty}^0 \frac {du}{(1-u)^2} = \int_1^\infty \frac {2du}{u^2}<\infty$$

Is this a correct solution, thanks.

Comment: Another nice example is $x^{-1/p'}$ times the indicator function on [-1,1] or its complement.  Which is in $L^p$ for appropriate $p'$.

Comment: So this correct, right?

Comment: You didn't show f is not in L^q.  Also you might want to say WLOG p>q or something to make it easier.

Comment: Is it enough if I do an integration of f^q?

Comment: This question looks a bit funny. Since $p<q$ implies $L^q \subset L^p$ you shouldn't be able to find both functions.

Comment: @Daron That's true for finite measure spaces, but not in general (an easy counterexample is counting measure on integers).   Aurel: it is enough if you actually get that $\int |f|^q=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

It's a reasonable solution. For extra clarity, you should mention that you work on $(0,\infty)$ with the Lebesgue measure, and what you actually construct is a function that belongs to $L^p$ **only** for one specific $p$. (This is something you definitely should have checked). This of course accomplishes the task. The second calculation is redundant: you could have just said that $g$ is like $f$, only with $q$ instead of $p$. No need to repeat the same integration steps.